# ImportError: cannot import name 'getargspec' from 'inspect' (C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, blockchain, importerror

```
 File "f:\drug-traceability-blockchain-maddy\src\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from web3 import Web3,HTTPProvider
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\web3\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from eth_account import (
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\eth_account\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from eth_account.account import (
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\eth_account\account.py", line 59, in <module>
    from eth_account.messages import (
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\eth_account\messages.py", line 26, in <module>
    from eth_account._utils.structured_data.hashing import (
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\eth_account\_utils\structured_data\hashing.py", line 9, in <module>
    from eth_abi import (
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\eth_abi\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from eth_abi.abi import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\eth_abi\abi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from eth_abi.codec import (
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\eth_abi\codec.py", line 16, in <module>
    from eth_abi.decoding import (
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\eth_abi\decoding.py", line 14, in <module>
    from eth_abi.base import (
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\eth_abi\base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .grammar import (
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\eth_abi\grammar.py", line 4, in <module>
    import parsimonious
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\parsimonious\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar, TokenGrammar
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\parsimonious\grammar.py", line 14, in <module>
    from parsimonious.expressions import (Literal, Regex, Sequence, OneOf,
  File "C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\parsimonious\expressions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from inspect import getargspec
ImportError: cannot import name 'getargspec' from 'inspect' (C:\Users\Swapn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py)
```

please help me .. how to solve this error.
this is blockchain project wgich i downloaded from github.
after that i was
npm install
npm start
truffle complile
truffle migrate
and for homepage of project
run app.py then i was receive this error.[Image of running errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WffU.png)

Comment: there is no `getargspec` in the inspect module.  there is a `getfullargspec` though.  getargspec is from the python2 days

Comment: either use python2 or find a different project

Comment: How to degrade python3 to python2 bro??

Comment: you don't... they are two separate interpreters.  You would need to download python2  and install it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try uninstalling web3 using `pip uninstall web3.py` and install the latest version from github using `pip install git+https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py.git`

Answer (score 6):

Either depreciate python

or go to python3.11/site-packages/parsimonious/expressions.py   and replace getargspec with getfullargspec

Comment: it worked for me, and the path may change if you use some other tool, eg poetry (pypoetry/virtualenvs). BTW, is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed web3.py through pip, it still won't work while the update is being approved it still install old version. Run **pip uninstall web3** to uninstall the old version, and run **pip install git+https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py.git** to install the new version off GitHub.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you saying that, "while the update is being approved," there is a reference to a legacy module that hasn't been officially supported in years?  Surely there's more to the story?

Comment: At the time i work.It install old web3 when I install it from pip install web3. so I install it from git and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this error while building a docker container (and thus editing the package manually is not an option), this might work.

Change the first line from

```
FROM python:3.11.5 # or whatever version you were using
```

to

```
FROM python:3.10.7
```